# Enter "Int" on Casio graphical calculator

Tags: calculator

Hi
I know this sounds like a really beginner question, but I cannot find how to enter the terms "Int" and "Ran#" into my calculator (Casio fx-9750GII)

My code is thus:

1->L

100->H

Int (Ran#×100)->A

Do

L_

H_

?->G

G[ne]A=>"KEEP TRYING"

G>A=>G->H

GG->L

LpWhile G[ne]A

"GOT IT"

EDIT: the code was all in one clump..

Comment: I presume you couldn't find the answer you needed [here](http://support.casio.com/pdf/004/fx-9750GII_Soft_E.pdf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my fx-9860G (which i believe is very similar):

Start with pressing the OPTN button. Then press F6 to get to the next page. Press F3 (PROB) to find Ran# (on F4) or F4 (NUM) to find Int (on F2). To summarize:

Int: OPTN, F6, F4 (NUM), F2 (Int).
Ran#: OPTN, F6, F3 (PROB), F4 (Ran#).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you press the OPTN button. Then, you press the NUM button (F5). Lastly, you press the Int button (F2). This is how I do it when I use the 
fx-9750GII calculator.